# Disable "Slow script" dialog in Safari while debugging javascript?

Tags: windows, safari, javascript-debugger

I'm using the built-in javascript debugger in Safari 4 on Windows (the WebKit Web Inspector), but when I'm stepping through code I keep getting the "Slow Script" dialog pestering me to abort/continue the script every few seconds. This is irritating.

Is there a way to turn this off or otherwise prevent it from prompting me every few seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the develop menu there should be an option to "disable runaway JavaScript timer"

Answer (score 1):

After you've enabled the "Develop" menu (Preferences -> Advanced -> "Show Develop menu in menu bar"), enable the Develop -> "Disable Runaway JavaScript Timer" option.